# SQL searching by name and surname

Tags: mysql

I have a huge document with names and surnames, it currently looks like this:

`"name1 surname1", "name2 surname2", "name3 surname3", "name4 surname4"....`

In database in `users` table there are columns `name` `surname` `email`.
What I need now is to find emails of the people from the list.
I cannot separate names and surnames since there are dozens of them.

What is the best way to find them? I guess `%like%` won't be working here. Please help me on this.

Note: What is difficult, some names and surnames are made of 3-4 words. This is not always only name and surname as 2 words.

Comment: show me sample content of table and required output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @mytxtvar TEXT;

SET @mytxtvar = LOAD_FILE('D:\\test.txt');
SELECT @mytxtvar;

SELECT email FROM user WHERE concat(name,' ',surname ) in @mytxtvar
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem.. isn't a simple query like this one enough?

```
select email 
from user 
where 
(name = 'name1' and username = 'surname1') or
(name = 'name2' and username = 'surname2') or
...
```

You just need to split your initial list with some language that you like or even a simple text editor and then execute the query

Comment: It is not that easy, some people are named like "Ari al mcdonalds 3rd"
No idea where is the name, where is surname. Thats difficult

Comment: Well, that changes a lot of things, i suggest you to put this detail in your main post so everybody can read it. By the way look at @Anurag Dadheech for a possible solution for this problem

Comment: @divHelper11 There should be some standard for retrieving name. if you yourself is not sure then how we can be.

Answer (score 0):

You can split each person on name and surname by using any language like JAVA,
Then make a batch query job for all names using loop and save the result wherever you want.
The query will be like this::

```
select email from user where name ='name1' and username ='surname1'
```